# "_card.scss" and "_type.scss" what are these and how to cancel them? (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working with Bootstrap v4.1.3
When trying to edit an element with class "card", I realized there are some codes like `_card.scss` and `_type.scss` adding style to my elements, and I don't even know how Bootstrap is calling them.
I would like to disable these codes so I don't have to rewrite the style.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want these styles to be in your bootstrap file then you can download their source code at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#source-files
to exclude these two files from the `bootstrap.scss`  & re-compile them.

```
 /*!
 * Bootstrap v4.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "root";
@import "reboot";
@import "type";
@import "images";
@import "code";
@import "grid";
@import "tables";
@import "forms";
@import "buttons";
@import "transitions";
@import "dropdown";
@import "button-group";
@import "input-group";
@import "custom-forms";
@import "nav";
@import "navbar";
@import "card";
@import "breadcrumb";
@import "pagination";
@import "badge";
@import "jumbotron";
@import "alert";
@import "progress";
@import "media";
@import "list-group";
@import "close";
@import "modal";
@import "tooltip";
@import "popover";
@import "carousel";
@import "utilities";
@import "print";
```